# pass data into modal from ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got simple table where I got files from my backend:

```
      <table class="table table-sm align-items-center table-hover table-flush responsive">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="lPart">Filename</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let file of fileUploads | async | filter: name | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10,
                currentPage: p }; let i = index">
            <td id="lPart" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight: normal;">
              <a href="http://localhost:3000/files/{{file.name}}{{file.ext}}">{{file.name}}</a>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" (click)="show()">{{file.name}}</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I tried add button which opens a modal

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" (click)="show()">{{file.name}}</button>
```

And there is modal

```
  <div [style.display]="showModal ? 'block' : 'none'" class="modal" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1"
                role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{file.name}}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <img src="http://localhost:3000/files/{{file.name}}{{file.ext}}"
                        id="imagepreview" style="width: 425px; height: 425px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"
                        (click)="hide()">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Problem is that this modal "works" only if is inside `<td>` tag

There is my method where I get files

```
  showFiles() {
    this.fileUploads = this.uploadService.getAccidentFiles();
    this.fileUploads.forEach(element => {
    });
  }
```

and for opening modal

```
  show() {
    this.showModal = true;
  }
```

Another problem is that if I got my modal inside `<td>` tag I got only last image from my uploaded files. I want to have next to filename button where I can click preview then I can show modal with image preview.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, bootstrap 4

Comment: Interesting that you choose to use a table instead of bootstrap 4's grid system - here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ . But I mean, it all eats the same. My understanding is that the template for modals needs to have its first parent as the <body>, not a <td>. Modals use the `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"` attributes on the button to display it - here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/. You could probably save the path to the image inside your own data- attribute for the button and tie it together with the onclick event tied to the modal.

Comment: There is table because I want to see mostly only files name and wen I click on any fileame I just can download image. But i want also have preview before download.

Another way I think is just get id of clicked item then make another service to get image with clciked id

Comment: Yah... you could just have a template modal with an image tag and change its source dynamically by using `onclick="document.getElementById('modal-image').src = this.src; document.getElementById('my-modal').show();"`.

Comment: Did this work to your liking?

Comment: Yes, thank you for tips. I already know how to do it

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help.